# python __str__ in inherited class

Tags: python

The following code to set up `__str__` function with an inherited class fails unless there is a "line" between self and the first attribute, i.e. if the line junk = 99, is commented out the program bombs

```
class TemplateBlock(object) :

    def __init__(self,                            
                 tidno      = 1):                
        self.tidno          = tidno              

    def __str__(self) :
        return '%.2d:' % (self.tidno)

class Block(TemplateBlock) :

    def __init__(self,                            
                 junk       = 99,                 
                 bidno      = 3) :
        TemplateBlock.__init__(self)                               
        #self.junk           = junk          
        self.bidno          = bidno

    def __str__(self) :
        return TemplateBlock.__str__(self) + '\n%.2d' %(self.bidno)

    def set(self,t) :                            
        self.tidno          = t.tidno            

tb = TemplateBlock(tidno=2)
b = Block(tb)
b.set(tb)
print(b)
```

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you include the traceback in your question? Saying it bombs is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Bombs meaning? Please provide the exception and traceback you're seeing.

Comment: Side-note: You're passing `tb` to `Block` which makes no sense; it becomes the `junk` or `bidno` argument, neither of which should be a `TemplateBlock`. And your superclass initializer call does not pass along a value for `tidno`, which necessitates that silly `.set(tb)` call, when you could define the subclass to accept and pass along `tidno` properly.

Comment: `junk` is absorbing a positional argument and causing `bidno` to take its default value. Which is a integer printable with `%d`. You pass in `tb` which is not an integer and hence not printable with `%d` and when you remove `junk` the incorrect type is assigned to `bidno`. Solution: pass an integer into `Block` constructor. Also `b.set(tb)` should be `b.set(tb.tidno)`

Comment: It is runnable via cut & paste from your source above, so I agree with @ShadowRanger, please describe your error: If your's isn't runnable, do you have perhaps a non-printable character on your "junk" line? or wonky indentation?

Answer (score 1):

Block(td) sets the self.bidno to td that is a TemplateBlock.
From there i suspect that '\n%.2d' %(self.bidno) throws an exception because bidno is not a number.